# OutofMemory exception with DiskLruCache when app runtime memory exceeds its maxmemory

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am using DiskLruCache provided in this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html
 for handling outofmemory problem but when the cache miss occurs it is decoding from the filedescriptor, while decoding it is growing heap size and it is not releasing the memory allocated (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()) it keeps on growing the runtime memory and when it exceeds the Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() it is raising outofmemory execption, how to handle this any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: post your code,how you used disk LRU Cache.

Comment: I followed the same code provided in the link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: then give less memory to disk LRU cache or follow, as mentioned here: http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error_3.html

Comment: Actually when the LruCache miss occurs it will decode the bitmap from filedescriptor and adds it in LruCache and removes least recently and adds it in the softreference<bitmap> hashset and uses inBitmap concept to avoid outofmemory execption, but the runtime memory is keep on growing at sometime it is exceeding and raising that problem

Comment: then you are not using it in correct way,because disk lru cache reserve only the memory size you gave to it.

Comment: I gave it as DiskLruCache.open(diskCacheDir, 1, 1,mCacheParams.diskCacheSize); where mCacheParams.diskCacheSize=10MB

Comment: do add your code in questio so that it can attract all users.

Comment: to make sure i am not doing any mistake I downlaoded the same code Bitmapfun.zip from developers site and added some extra urls in images.java and when I run the app I got the Outofmemory exception when the bitmaps are decoding from filedescriptors